# how fork() process works (operating system)

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, posix

I am confused about `fork()`. For example, what will be the output of the following code?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int value = 5;

int main()  {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)   {   value += 15; return 0; }
    else if (pid > 0>) { wait (NULL); printf (“Value = %d”, value); return 0} 
}
```

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node22.html) , it should be a useful tutorial!

Answer (score 4):

The function [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) creates a new process that is a complete copy of the original process. The new process has its own memory and its own copy of all variables.

In the new child process the returned `pid` value is zero. The child adds 15 to its variable `value` and exits in the line:

```
if (pid == 0) { value += 15; return 0; }
```

The `value` is 5 in the original process. The original parent process has `pid` greater than zero and it goes to:

```
else if (pid > 0) { wait (NULL); printf("Value = %d", value); return 0; }
```

This line prints: `Value = 5`

Answer (score 1):

The output will be "Value = 5".

The fork function will create a new process (child process) with its own address space. The child process will receive a copy of the parents process data region, heap and stack. Therefore, modifying the variable `value` in the child process won't affect the variable `value` in the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't know or don't quite understand what `fork` does. Like Orest Hera and reffox both said, `fork()` spans a new process.

You should also know that the parent process (the once actually calling `fork`) will get the `pid` of the child process as a result from `fork`.

The child process starts at the point, where `fork` finished and returns 0 instead, thus giving the processes the chance to check, who they are:

```
var x = 7;
pid = fork();

if(pid < 0)
{
    perror("failing to create a child process");
    return SOME_ERROR;
}

if(pid == 0)
{
    /* I'm the child process */
    x = 9;
    /* only I see that, my dad doesn't even notice that this happened */
    ...
} else {
    /* I'm the parent process */
    ...
    /* waiting for my child to die,
       otherwise a zombie will be created,
       and I DO mean a zombie */
    wait(0);

    /* the child is gone, now I can do whatever I want to */

}
```